# Python3: achieve ssh by pexpect

Tags: python, ssh

I am new to use pexpect module complete ssh function by python. as you see, could you please tell me what's the usage of "-l" behind ssh command? It seems that -l is not a way to use ssh.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
import sys

host="xxx"
user="xxx"
password="xxxx"
command="ls -l"
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l %s %s %s'%(user, host, command)) # what's the usage of "-l" behind ssh? if I remove "-l" , it will come an error.
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Comment: The `-l` parameter is used to specify the user to connect as.

Answer (score 0):

As per `man ssh`:

```
-l login_name Specifies the user to log in as on the remote machine.  This also may be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.
```

In you case, you may avoid using `-l` by using:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s %s'%(user, host, command))
```